# Problem with SAGA batch processing

Tags: interpolation, saga, point-cloud

I have a series of point clouds in LAZ format that contain points identified as ground. I want to interpolate these points with the Multilevel B-Spline algorithm of Saga GIS and export the clouds to sdat or GeoTIFF formats. Since there are 96 files, I wanted to automate the processing. All the point clouds are in a single folder. This is the code I have used:

```
    @ECHO OFF
REM **********************************
REM Interpolar con Multilevel Bspline
REM Autor: Gerardo Jiménez Delgado
REM ***********************************
REM *************RUTAS*****************
REM Ruta al ejecutable de saga_cmd
PATH="C:\Program Files\SAGA";%PATH%
REM Ruta a los datos
SET WORK=C:\EXP\Datos
REM **********************************
REM Tool: Multilevel B-Spline
REM **********************************
FOR %%i IN (%WORK%\*.laz) DO (
    SAGA_CMD grid_spline 4 "Multilevel B-Spline Interpolation" ^
    -SHAPES="%WORK%\%%~nxi" ^
    -FIELD="Z" ^
    -TARGET=0 ^
    -USER_SIZE=0.5 ^
    -GRID "%WORK%\Target_Grid.sg-grd-z" ^
    -TARGET_USER_FITS=0 ^
    -TARGET_TEMPLATE="input file" ^
    -TARGET_OUT_GRID="%WORK%\Target_Grid.sg-grd-z" ^
    -METHOD=0 ^
    -EPSILON=0.0001 ^
    -LEVEL_MAX=11
)
PAUSE
```

The code does run but it sends me the following error message:

```
[Multilevel B-Spline] Execution started...
```

Multilevel B-Spline: could not initialize data objects
Error: executing tool [Multilevel B-Spline]

I wonder if I have to convert the point clouds to other format first in order that they can be interpolated, but I am really stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that Saga's interpolation algorithm does not understand first hand las/laz format. I does need the point cloud to be converted to a saga point file. The following code does exactly this:

```
@ECHO OFF
```

PUSHD %~dp0
PATH="C:\Program Files\SAGA";%PATH%
SET SAGA_TLB=C:\MyTools
SET WORK=C:\EXP\Datos
SET PUNTOS=C:\EXP\POINTS
REM Tool: Import Point Cloud
FOR %%i IN (%WORK%*.laz) DO (
SAGA_CMD io_pdal 0 ^
-FILES="%WORK%%%~nxi" ^
-VARS=1 ^
-VAR_TIME=0 ^
-VAR_INTENSITY=0 ^
-VAR_SCANANGLE=0 ^
-VAR_RETURN=0 ^
-VAR_RETURNS=0 ^
-VAR_CLASSIFICATION=0 ^
-VAR_USERDATA=0 ^
-VAR_EDGE=0 ^
-VAR_DIRECTION=0 ^
-VAR_SOURCEID=0 ^
-VAR_COLOR_RED=0 ^
-VAR_COLOR_GREEN=0 ^
-VAR_COLOR_BLUE=0 ^
-VAR_COLOR=0 ^
-RGB_RANGE=1 ^
-POINTS="C:\EXP\POINTS\data%%~ni.sg-pts"
)
PAUSE

In this case all the pointclouds in laz format in the datos folder, are converted to individual saga point files in the folder Points.

Now you can interpolate the points with the following code:

```
@ECHO OFF
```

REM **********************************
REM Interpolar con Multilevel Bspline
REM Autor: Gerardo Jiménez Delgado
REM ***********************************
REM *************RUTAS*****************
REM Ruta al ejecutable de saga_cmd
PATH="C:\Program Files\SAGA";%PATH%
REM Ruta a los datos
SET WORK=C:\EXP\Points
SET SURF=C:\EXP\RESULTADOS
REM **********************************
REM Tool: Multilevel B-Spline
REM **********************************
FOR %%i IN (%WORK%*.sg-pts) DO (
SAGA_CMD grid_spline 4 "Multilevel B-Spline Interpolation" -SHAPES "%WORK%%%~nxi" -FIELD "Z" -TARGET_USER_SIZE 0.5 -TARGET_USER_FITS=0 -TARGET_OUT_GRID "C:\EXP\RESULTADOS\data%%~ni.sgrd" -METHOD 0 -EPSILON=0.0001 -LEVEL_MAX 11)
PAUSE

All point files in the points folder are interpolated and the resulting surface is stored in the Resultados folder as a saga binary grid.

Of course you can change the code to suit your needs, I already made som test with 6, 11, 24 and 109 files and I have no problem. Of course you can merge both codes in a single file, with little modifications, nevertheless I prefer to check each process separately, but that is me.